# Шаблоны в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Народ, можете объяснить, как работает шаблон в C++?
Я прочитал книгу Страуструпа, но так и не врубился с суть.
Помогите, пожалуйста, объяснить, как работает на примерах и в подробностях рассказать, что из себя они представляют?

Answer (score 5):

Приближение такое - шаблоны, это крутые макросы, макросы, которые не просто заменой работают, а с делают замену более интеллектуально. Посмотрим на такой простой шаблон поиска максимума двух значений

```
template <class T>
const T& max ( const T& a, const T& b ) {
  return (a<b)?b:a;     // or: return comp(a,b)?b:a; for the comp version
}
```

Первую строку пока не смотрим. Видим, что есть функция, которая принимает два параметра-ссылки одного типа (Т), пытается их сравнить и возвращает ссылку на больший из них. И сам код понятен теперь должен быть. А первая строка, это просто такая запись для компилятора, что бы он не искал по всему коду тип T, а знал, что это специальный тип.
Что же происходит дальше?
а теперь компилятор компилирует код и видит вызов к примеру
    int x = max(3,4);
он видит, что у него есть такая функция, но она шаблонная. Поэтому он смотрит на аргументы, и на возвращаемое значение и понимает, что если T будет равно 'int', то все сходится (эта процедура называется "выводом типов аргументов"). Дальше компилятор берет шаблонную функцию и делает в ней замены и в реальный скомпилированный код попадает такое

```
const int& max ( const int& a, const int& b ) {
  return (a<b)?b:a;
}
```

а теперь припустим, что встретился вызов такой

```
int z = max("5", 4.5);
```

компилятор смотрит на это и понимает, что он никак не подберет такое значение для T, что бы у него сошлись типы аргументов.

Но это простые варианты. В других случаях, например, когда передаются объекты, компилятор пытается подбирать тип с учетом преобразований, не всегда логичных с первого взгляда.

Answer (score 0):

В первом приближении шаблон можно рассматривать как формальный параметр функции, но не значение, а тип данных.
Если есть функция расчета площади круга от радиуса, то её можно вызвать для радиуса 1,2,3,4,.... , с шаблонами примерно так же - функция может быть "вызвана" для работы с int, char,... и пользовательскими классами.